# How To Prevent Form Submission And Tell Users That Input Cannot Be Three Numbers

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have spent so many hours searching for either an HTML input tag or Javascript that prevents form submission when input is only 3 numbers.
I don't want to use characters because my input field only requires numbers.

```
<input name="Code" value="000" onchange="leadingZeros(this)" onkeyup="leadingZeros(this)"
   onclick="leadingZeros(this)" autocomplete="off" id="myInput"   type='text' required=""   />

function leadingZeros(input) {
if(!isNaN(input.value) && input.value.length === 1) {
  input.value = '000' + input.value;
}
```

}

I am using the code above on my form to force the input of three zeros (000) before the numbers users provide in the input field.

Some users might forget to fill out that field and proceed to submit my form and the form will get submitted because it detects that the field isn't empty.

Some users forget to fill out the field and I only get the three zeros (000) when the form gets submitted.

I want to prevent the form submission when they forget to input their numbers after the first three zeros and tell users that **INPUT CAN NOT BE 3 NUMBERS**.

That will remind them that the first three zeros had been in the input field and they still have to provide their numbers after it.

How can I do this, please?

Comment: Instead of describing it, please give a few example of valid and invalid input.

Comment: (also, if I understand correctly, my approach would be to use an onblur handler that fixes a bad input where the intended input can be inferred unequivocally)

Comment: I know I could do that but adding the solution that I seek would help stop errors in submission. Not everyone would follow the instructions unless your force them to and the first three zeros are very important to the submission results.

Comment: How do I use the onblur handler that you suggested please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation). For instance, to force an input of three zeroes followed by one or several digits:

```html
<input pattern="^000\d+$" required />
```

Comment: If your answer is a one line link to the docs, consider not posting it as answer. This website is not intended to rehash docs, and links rot.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your codee like this to achieve the purpose.
Read the comments for moree understanding

**HTML code**

```
  <form id="myForm">
    <input name="Code" value="000" autocomplete="off" id="myInput" type='text' required=""   />
    </form>
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
document.querySelector('#form').addEventListener("submit", function(e) {

//prevent default behaviour
e.preventDefault()

// collect input value
let inputValue = document.querySelector('#myInput').value

//check whether input value is not number or less than 3 char
 if(!isNaN(inputValue) || inputValue.length < 3){
 alert('Error. Input must be a number and more than 3 characters')

    }
//  submit the form data with with AJAX
    })
```

If you do not know how to use AJAX nor do not intend to use AJAX, you may have your HTML written like this with button/ input **type='button'** so that the form do not submit automatically when user press on the button

```
    <form id="myForm">
    <input name="Code" value="000" autocomplete="off" id="myInput" type='text' required=""   />
     <button type="button" id="myButton"> submit </button>
    </form>
```

Then you use JavaScript to submit the form when the button is clicked like this

```
document.querySelector('#myButton').addEventListener("click", function(e) {

    //prevent default behaviour
    e.preventDefault()

    // collect input value
    let inputValue = document.querySelector('#myInput').value

    //check whether input value is not number or less than 3 char
     if(!isNaN(inputValue) || inputValue.length < 3){
     alert('Error. Input must be a number and more than 3 characters')

        }

    //submit form
    document.querySelector('#form').submit()

        })
```